# RecyclerView goes blank when the Firebase database reference is changed on Spinner item selected

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

So, when the activity `ViewAll` is launch from the `MainActivity`, it passes the variable `language` by intent `extra` that would point to the Firebase database node which is then fetch in to the `recyclerView` to display the items. Everything works initially until when the `language` is changed from the spinner selected item which is also the firebase database node reference. So, the issue I am facing is that changing the firebase database reference by spinner item selected the `recyclerView` goes blank. This is driving me mad don't know what to do. Please excuse me for my bad coding skills.

```
public class ViewAll extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner selectLanguage;
    private boolean loadNextDataCalled = false; // Flag to track if loadNextData has been called
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private List<DataModel> dataList;
    private String lastChildKey = "";
    private boolean isLoading = false;
    public String language;
    private List<DataModel> completeDataList; // Holds the complete dataset
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);

        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        completeDataList = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize the completeDataList


        EditText search = findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // No action needed
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                performSearch(s.toString());
                if (!loadNextDataCalled) {
                    loadNextData("search");
                    loadNextDataCalled = true; // Set the flag to true after calling loadNextData
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // No action needed
            }
        });
        search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
                {
                    loadNextData("search");
                    performSearch(search.getText().toString());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        language = intent.getStringExtra("language");
        syncFirebase(language);

        TextView viewAllTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_ViewAll);
        viewAllTitle.setText(language);

        ImageButton goBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        goBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new DataAdapter(dataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(language.toLowerCase());

        loadNextData("scroll");

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (dy > 0) {
                    int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount();
                    int totalItemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount();
                    int firstVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (!isLoading && (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                        loadNextData("scroll");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        selectLanguage = findViewById(R.id.selectLanguage);
        populateSpinner();
    }
    private void syncFirebase(String language)
    {
        DatabaseReference fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(language.toLowerCase());
        fbRef.keepSynced(true);
    }
    public void populateSpinner()
    {
        ArrayList<String> languageList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Retrieve the string array from resources
        String[] languages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language);

        // Add the languages to the list
        for (String language : languages)
        {
            languageList.add(language);
        }

        // Populate the languageList into the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ViewAll.this, R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown, languageList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item_layout);
        selectLanguage.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set the popup theme for the spinner
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            selectLanguage.setDropDownVerticalOffset(selectLanguage.getHeight());
            selectLanguage.setDropDownHorizontalOffset(selectLanguage.getWidth());
            selectLanguage.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }

        // Set the on item selected listener for the spinner
        selectLanguage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                language = selectedItem;
                loadItemsByLanguage(language);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
        // Set the spinner selection to "Bengali"
        String languageToSelect = language.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + language.substring(1);;
        int position = ((ArrayAdapter<String>) selectLanguage.getAdapter()).getPosition(languageToSelect);
        selectLanguage.setSelection(position);

        // Manually invoke onItemSelected after setting the selection
        selectLanguage.performItemClick(
                selectLanguage.getSelectedView(),
                position,
                selectLanguage.getAdapter().getItemId(position)
        );
    }
    private void loadItemsByLanguage(String language) {
        // Clear the existing data list and complete data list
        dataList.clear();
        completeDataList.clear();

        // Reset the last child key and isLoading flag
        lastChildKey = "";
        isLoading = false;

        // Update the title TextView with the selected language
        TextView viewAllTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_ViewAll);
        viewAllTitle.setText(language);

        // Update the database reference to the selected language
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(language.toLowerCase());

        // Load the first batch of data
        loadNextData("search");
    }

    private void loadNextData(String scrollOrsearch) {
        if(scrollOrsearch.equals("search"))
        {
            isLoading = true;

            final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            databaseReference.orderByKey().startAt(lastChildKey)
                    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                            if (!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(lastChildKey)) {
                                lastChildKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                DataModel dataModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataModel.class);
                                dataModel.setParentKey(dataSnapshot.getRef().getKey());
                                dataList.add(dataModel);
                                completeDataList.add(dataModel); // Add to completeDataList
                                adapter.notifyItemInserted(dataList.size() - 1);
                            }

                            isLoading = false;
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                            // Handle child changed event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Handle child removed event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                            // Handle child moved event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            isLoading = false;
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

        }
        else if(scrollOrsearch.equals("scroll"))
        {
            isLoading = true;

            final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            databaseReference.orderByKey().startAt(lastChildKey).limitToFirst(10)
                    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                            if (!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(lastChildKey)) {
                                lastChildKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                DataModel dataModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataModel.class);
                                dataModel.setParentKey(dataSnapshot.getRef().getKey());
                                dataList.add(dataModel);
                                completeDataList.add(dataModel); // Add to completeDataList
                                adapter.notifyItemInserted(dataList.size() - 1);
                            }

                            isLoading = false;
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                            // Handle child changed event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Handle child removed event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                            // Handle child moved event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            isLoading = false;
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void performSearch(String query) {
        List<DataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataModel dataModel : completeDataList) { // Search through completeDataList
            // Perform your search filtering logic here
            if (dataModel.getSongname().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(dataModel);
            }
        }
        // Log the filtered list to check if the search is working correctly
        Log.d("Search", "Filtered List Size: " + filteredList.size());
        for (DataModel dataModel : filteredList) {
            Log.d("Search", "Filtered Item: " + dataModel.getSongname());
        }

        // Update the adapter with the filtered list
        adapter.setData(filteredList);
    }

    public void allData()
    {

    }

    private class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<DataModel> dataList;

        public DataAdapter(List<DataModel> dataList) {
            this.dataList = dataList;
        }
        public void setData(List<DataModel> newDataList) {
            dataList.clear();
            dataList.addAll(newDataList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view_all, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            DataModel dataModel = dataList.get(position);
            holder.songNameTextView.setText(dataModel.getSongname());
            holder.composerTextView.setText(dataModel.getComposer());

            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                    .load(dataModel.getYoutubeThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.worshiplyric) // Placeholder image resource
                    .error(R.drawable.worshiplyric) // Error image resource
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.e("Glide", "Thumbnail image loading failed: " + e);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.d("Glide", "Thumbnail image loaded successfully");
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(holder.thumbnailImageView);

            holder.lvItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String songId = dataModel.getParentKey();
                    String parentNode = language;

                    Intent intent_lyricsActivity = new Intent(holder.lvItem.getContext(), LyricActivity.class);
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("lyrics", dataModel.getEnglishlyric());
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("artistpicture", dataModel.getSurl());
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("songname", dataModel.getSongname());
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("songId", songId);
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("artistName", dataModel.getComposer());
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("language", parentNode);
                    intent_lyricsActivity.putExtra("composer", dataModel.getComposer());

                    holder.lvItem.getContext().startActivity(intent_lyricsActivity);
                }
            });

            holder.btn_Like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) //If User is Signed In, User will be able to like the song
                    {
                        FirebaseUser userCurrent = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Users");

                        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                //Check if User Id exists in the User database
                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userCurrent.getUid()))
                                {
                                    FirebaseDatabase rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                    DatabaseReference parentRef = rootRef.getReference("Users");
                                    DatabaseReference userIdRef = parentRef.child(userCurrent.getUid());
                                    DatabaseReference userLikeRef = userIdRef.child("songlike");

                                    userLikeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                        {
                                            //Check if User Id has like the song
                                            // If currentUser Id has the clicked song id
                                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(dataModel.getParentKey()))
                                            {
                                                //Remove from the like song
                                                parentRef.child(userCurrent.getUid()).child("songlike").child(dataModel.getParentKey()).removeValue();
                                                //Toast.makeText(holder.btn_Like.getContext(), "Song Removed from likes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                holder.btn_Like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24);
                                            }
                                            else if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(dataModel.getParentKey()))
                                            {
                                                //TODO: Use Map
                                                String parentNode = dataModel.getParentKey();
                                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                                map.put("songTitle", dataModel.getSongname());
                                                map.put("artistPicture", dataModel.getSurl());
                                                map.put("artistName", dataModel.getComposer());
                                                map.put("lyric", dataModel.getEnglishlyric());
                                                map.put("composer", dataModel.getComposer());
                                                map.put("language", parentNode);

                                                //Toast.makeText(holder.btn_Like.getContext(), parentNode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                //Add the song to like
                                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("songlike").child(dataModel.getParentKey())
                                                        .setValue(map)
                                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                                                        {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused)
                                                            {
                                                                //Toast.makeText(holder.btn_Like.getContext(), "Song Added to likes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                holder.btn_Like.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24);
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                                                        {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                                                            {
                                                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                        {
                                            // Handle the error
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                            {
                                // Handle the error
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Guest Users will not be able to like the song
                        Toast.makeText(holder.btn_Like.getContext(), "You are not sign in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Check the "songlike" status
            checkSongLikeStatus(holder, dataModel.getParentKey());
        }

        private void checkSongLikeStatus(ViewHolder holder, String parentKey)
        {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                DatabaseReference songLikeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("Users")
                        .child(user.getUid())
                        .child("songlike")
                        .child(parentKey);

                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {
                            holder.btn_Like.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            holder.btn_Like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                };

                songLikeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.btn_Like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dataList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView thumbnailImageView;
            TextView songNameTextView;
            TextView composerTextView;
            RelativeLayout lvItem;
            ImageButton btn_Like;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                thumbnailImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImageView);
                songNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.songNameTextView);
                composerTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.composerTextView);
                lvItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutItem);
                btn_Like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_fav);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **500** (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).